# Why are changes to the Eclipse Redhat JBOSS launch/run configuration not being saved?

Tags: eclipse, jboss

I have been trying to update the program arguments of my JBOSS EAP 7 server within eclipse in order to update:  "**--server-config=standalone.xml**"  to " 
 **--server-config=*standalone-full.xml***". However whenever I make this change (either directly in the launch config file at:***workspace_name.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.debug.core.launches*** or by double clicking the server name and then clicking "Open Launch Configuration") it is simply not applied and it is overwritten. Can anyone shed some light on this? Will be appreciated.

Redhat JBOSS EAP 7.0 on:
Eclipse (Spring Tool Suite)
Version: 3.9.2.RELEASE
Build Id: 201712210947
Platform: Eclipse Oxygen.2 (4.7.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just found the answer to this question:

It seems that eclipse allows you to edit he launch configuration and apply it but it does not actually apply it. The way around it is to edit the Runtime Environment Configuration by clicking the Runtime Environment link above the Launch Configuration link and then simply browse for the configuration file that is required...how bizzare. It works for this particular config element but I'm not sure where the rest of the config changes must be effected.

Comment: Be sure to accept your own answer as if you dont, it shows up in unaccepted answers lists!  I like your profile wording, nice.